# How long is start date? 00h00mm00ss or a 24hour period?

Tags: civimember

I have simple membership statuses that say:
Status 1: from membership date to start date
Status 2: from start date to end date.

On start date, the membership has changed from not member to member but the status stayed on Status 1. (I have set the cron every hour so it would be updated the way it should).

When is the time limit: 00h00mm00ss or a 24hour period?

How does it work in CiviCRM?

Comment: I believe that the status changes 1 day after. So if the start date is today then tomorrow the status is updated.

Comment: thanks Jaap. I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: there is a Scheduled Job that runs - i think the default is nightly but you can set it more often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing, here is how it works.

If we use again my example with twice the same event date **3rd of April**:

Status 1: from membership date to start date
Status 2: from start date to end date.

Status 1 will change **by the end** of the 3rd of April which means start date from the previous status is "Master" and start date lasts 24 hours. Status 2 will appear on the 4th of April. And this is not related to cron Job.

So if you want to start Status 2 on the 3rd of April at 00h00'00", for example if an Insurance is running from this date or if the member has to be of legal age, then set the end event of Status 1 on start date and -1 Day.

Comment: hmm interesting. good you found a workaround. but am wondering if there isn't something else we are missing here but i don't feel i have fully grasped the workflow